# Is there any straightforward option of unpacking a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I do something like this

```
some_obj = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
first, *rest = some_obj
```

I'll get a list, but I want it in 2 dictionaries: `first = {"a": 1}` and `rest = {"b": 2, "c": 3}`. As I understand, I can make a function, but I wonder if I can make it in one line, like in javascript with spread operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if there is a reliable way to achieve this in one line, But here is one method.

First unpack the `key`s and `values`(`.items()`). Using `some_obj` only iterate through the keys.

```
>>> some_obj = {"a":1, "b":2, "c": 3}
>>> first, *rest = some_obj.items()
```

But this will return a tuple,

```
>>> first
('a', 1)
>>> rest
[('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

But you can again convert back to dict with just a `dict` call.

```
>>> dict([first])
{'a': 1}
>>> dict(rest)
{'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: I think this is as good as it gets. Python `dict`s have guaranteed insertion order since 3.7, but there's not much method support to leverage this like there is for iterables. For example, you can iterate in insertion order, but there's no indexing or slicing. One odd thing is that `OrderedDict` seemed redundant after 3.7, but its `OrderedDict.popitem` can remove the first or last element while `dict.popitem` can't.

Answer (score 3):

```
k = next(iter(some_obj))  # get the first key
first = {k: some_obj.pop(k)}
rest = some_obj
```

If you need to keep the original object intact - note this degrades from *O(1)* to *O(n)* in both time and space:

```
k = next(iter(some_obj))
rest = some_obj.copy()
first = {k: rest.pop(k)}
```

Answer (score 3):

A oneliner inspired by Abdul Niyas P M's:

```
first, rest = dict([next(i := iter(some_obj.items()))]), dict(i)
```

Uses an assignment expression, introduced in Python 3.8 almost two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

@AbdulNiyasPM's answer is perfectly fine, but since you asked for a one-liner, here's one way to do it (though you would have to do `from operator import itemgetter` first):

```
first, rest = map(dict, itemgetter(slice(0, 1), slice(1, None))(list(some_obj.items())))
```

If you prefer not to import anything, you can use a similar one-liner with a `lambda` function that takes one fixed argument and the rest as variable-length arguments:

```
first, rest = map(dict, (lambda f, *r: ((f,), r))(*some_obj.items()))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ImpeccableEllipticalGeeklog

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote - this is very gross and the question asked for a "straightforward option"  :)   Just because someone asks for a one-liner, doesn't mean we have to indulge it..